# Change page title inside another include - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm just starting to learn Laravel and want to know how to go about doing the below. I'll give the code then explain.

I have a file `includes/head.blade.php`. this file contains things you find inside the `<head>`. So it contains `<title>@yield('title')</title>` If I now include this file in a page let say `pages/about.blade.php` like this `@include('includes.head')`, How then can I modify the `<title>` nested inside the include using this line `@section('title', ' bout Us')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the blade file like `@include('includes.head')` then you cannot do `<title>@yield('title')</title>` in `head.blade.php` . Correct way to do this is passing the value while including the file like :

```
@include('includes.head',['title'=>'About Us'])
```

and in `head.blade.php` you must do like:

```
<title>
   @if(isset($title))
       {{ $title }}
   @endif 
</title>
```

But if you `extends` the **heade.blade.php** then you can do like this :

**head.blade.php**

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
```

**about.blade.php**

```
@extends('includes.head')
@section('title')
    {{ "About Us" }}
@endsection
```

For more info [Check this](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/248/knowing-all-the-blade-template-commands)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `@include` like this, check this [DOC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade).

```
@include('includes.head', ['title' => 'About Us'])
```

and the `title` should be print as,

```
<title>{{ $title }}</title>
```

---

**FOR the best practice**

Check the laravel blade [`templating`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#template-inheritance) feature,

you can define a `master layout`, extending that layout you can create new views. As like in the this [DOC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#template-inheritance).

*`master.blade.php`*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*`about.blade.php`*

```
@extends('master')

@section('title', 'About Us') // this will replace the **title section** in master.blade
//OR
//@section('title')
//    About Us
//@endsection

@section('sidebar')
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```